# WatchService OVERFLOW - what happens and how can my files be safely processed?

Tags: java, watchservice, file-monitoring

I'm thinking of refactoring my current cronjob based filemonitoring (running every night) with a more dynamic file monitoring.

Reading the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/notification.html) it mentions

> OVERFLOW – Indicates that events might have been lost or discarded.
>   You do not have to register for the OVERFLOW event to receive it.

What does this mean in practice with the watched files?

Currently I have a file "inbox" that receives 4 files every night from different sources.

My question is basically, are there any chance that a file will be missed due to  OVERFLOW? If so, how can I make it more safe so that all files will always be processed when they arrive, or at least soon thereafter? Or do I need to make some kind of `if(OVERFLOW) -> processFolder()?`

Comment: If this is only that many files, you are very unlikely to get an overflow, or it means the watch service implementation for your OS and JVM has a real problem :p

Comment: Yeah I assumed so also, but it's not that clear when overflows could occur, and I need to be sure that the file is processed within 6h of arrival. But if i take the overflow case and make a manual processing of the folder at that time I'm sure to not miss any files?

Comment: Well, there is _always_ the case for race conditions :) But basically, the only likely case when you'll get an overflow is if you fail to process events in time, _or_ the OS side of the service has a full queue and cannot add any more events

Comment: Ok, then I should be fairly safe :) Feel free to put comments as an answer if you want the points.